# checking if internet connection with cordova not working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I'm using this plugin to see if my phone has internet connection:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

But not working.. show me this error:

`D/CordovaLog( 3169): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 44 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined`

My function :

````
var App = {

```
//Application Constructor
init: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

//Bind Event Listeners
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

//Event Handle
onDeviceReady: function() {
    //Fast click
    FastClick.attach(document.body);          

    Usuario.verificarOnline();
    DataBase.init();

    alert(App._internet());
},

getUrl: function(){        
    return App.url;
},

//verificar conexao com internet
_internet: function(){
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = false;
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = true;
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = true;
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = true;
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = true;
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = true;
        states[Connection.CELL]     = true;
        states[Connection.NONE]     = false;

   return states[networkState];
}
```

};

````

Comment: Did you include line 44?

Comment: I gave only one alert in the outcome of this line:
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

Answer (score 1):

Either it means you didn't install the plugin :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

or it means you didn't wait for the device to be ready before calling your function:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function()
{
    // Call the function
}
```

Comment: I added the main posting now.

Comment: I don't have any problem with your code. The problem is really linked to your plugin that is somehow not installed. Can you try to post what happens when removing (`cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-network-information`) and installing again the plugin (`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information`) ?

Comment: Você quis dizer: O erro é esse:
The error is this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined

Comment: This is not a CLI (Command Line Interface) error, this a console error. The CLI where you type you commands like `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-network-information` or `dir`, `ls`, etc.